# Extract the best attributes from a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table`:

```
> (a <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
                   attribute=c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                   importance=1:6,
                   key=c("id","importance")))
   id attribute importance
1:  1         a          1
2:  1         b          2
3:  1         c          3
4:  2         a          4
5:  2         b          5
6:  3         c          6
```

I want:

**--1--** sort it by the second key in the *decreasing* order (i.e., the most important attributes should come first)

**--2--** select the *top* 2 (or 10) attributes for each `id`, i.e.:

```
   id attribute importance
3:  1         c          3
2:  1         b          2
5:  2         b          5
4:  2         a          4
6:  3         c          6
```

**--3--** pivot the above:

```
id  attribute.1 importance.1 attribute.2 importance.2
 1            c            3           b            2
 2            b            5           a            4
 3            c            6          NA           NA
```

It appears that the last operation can be done with something like:

```
a[,{ 
  tmp <- .SD[.N:1]; 
  list(a1 = tmp$attribute[1], 
       i1 = tmp$importance[1])
}, by=id]
```

Is this The Right Way?

How do I do the first two tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do the first two tasks like this:

```
a[a[, .I[.N:(.N-1)], by=list(id)]$V1]
```

The inner `a[, .I[.N:(.N-1)], ,by=list(id)]` gives you the indices in the order you require for every unique group in `id`.  Then you subset `a` with the `V1` column (which has the indices in the order you require).

You'll have to take care of negative indices here, maybe something like:

```
a[a[, .I[seq.int(.N, max(.N-1L, 1L))], by=list(id)]$V1]
```